Umbraco 13 Member login cookie persists even if isPersistent set to false
I have a Members area (not Users) which is password protected. In a SurfaceController, I am using IMemberSignInManager PasswordSignInAsync to sign a member in if other various tests are passed.
var result = await _memberSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, true);

However, with the "isPersistent" setting (3rd one) set to false, I get a cookie with a 1 year expiry date, which persists after closing and reopening the browser.
If I set "isPersistent" to true, I get a cookie that lasts 2 weeks. Is there a way to adjust the expiry date of the cookie?
I am assuming that if "isPersistent" is set to false, that the login only lasts for the current browser session - closing and reopening the browser would require the member to login again.
I have tried clearing cookies in the browser before testing. Logging out does remove the cookie.
